Intersection Non-Emptiness for Two-Way Finite Automata
We know that checking the emptiness of intersection of an unbounded number of deterministic finite automata is PSpace-complete, and that just the emptiness problem for a nondeterministic two-way finite state automaton is also PSpace-complete.
Is there anything known about checking the emptiness of intersection of an unbounded number of two-way state automata? Maybe even deterministic ones.
Googling did not give anything. But maybe some hypothesis/connection with other problems/etc.?

Unlike one-way models, intersection of 2-way NFAs is "cheap":
Given 2-way NFAs $A_1,A_2$, you can construct a 2-way NFA $B$ for their intersection that works as follows: it first behaves like $A_1$, and once the accepting state is reached, it resets the head to the left marker (using a single state), and starts at the initial state of $A_2$.
This can be easily extended to any number of NFAs, and the construction has linear size.
Thus, the non-emptiness problem for intersection of 2-way NFAs reduces to non-emptiness of a single 2-way NFA. So still PSPACE-complete.
